Dealing with Low variance categorical variables on cox regression
I am fitting a time varying cox model to my survival data, and I remove one arbitrary level from each categories, to create the baseline hazard. I have some low variance categorical variables. If I remove them, will they contribute to the baseline hazard? How should I handle the low variance categorical variables?

This is rather unclear. Do you mean you remove one level from each categorical variable? You don't have to do that, any software will do it automatically. And what do you mean by "low variance categorical variable"?  Technically, a categorical variable doesn't have a variance. Probably you should let the software handle the variables, at least to start.

Yes, I remove one level from each categorical variable to create the baseline hazard. I am using the lifelines library, CoxTimeVaryingFitter specifically, and I am not quite sure if it handles the baseline hazard automatically. @PeterFlom

A Cox survival regression, by design, does not involve the baseline hazard at all. Under the proportional hazards assumption, the form of the baseline hazard is completely irrelevant. You can infer a baseline hazard from the results of the Cox model and the data set, but the “baseline hazard” is handled “automatically” (I.e., ignored) by any reputable Cox regression software. The software you use is highly reputable.
